# Intersection of subspaces is less than sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

If $S,R$ are finite dimensional subspaces of $P$ can we conclude 
$$
\text{dim}(S \cap R) \leq \text{dim}(S),\text{dim}(R) \leq \text{dim}(S+R)
$$
without knowing anything about $S,R$

Comment: Is $P$ finite-dimensional?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because we know that

$$ \text{if }  A \subset B  \text{, then } \dim {A} \le \dim{B}, $$

and we know that, as sets

$$A \cap B \subset A,B \subset A+B.$$